# Change property based on condition

Tags: c#, linq

Consider the following snippet of code:

```
var employeeDetails = db.Employees.Where(a => a.Username == username).Select(b => b).FirstOrDefault();

var emailTemp = new EmailTemplate
{
   EmailTo = employeeDetails.Email,
   Subject = somesubject,
   EmailFrom = "from@mydomain.com",
   EmailDelivered = "No",
   EmailPriority = "Normal",
   EmailReference = formId
   EmailTemplateId = 1
};
```

`employeeDetails` is a simple linq query which returns me the users record from the employees table. What I'm trying to achieve is send this out to two users. The first should get sent to the person who has submitted the form and another to their manager. The only property that changes is `EmailTemplateId` from 1 to 2.

1 = user

2 = manager

I can't seem to figure out how to go about it. I have the managers column in my employee table.

I would appreciate it if someone can shed some light on this for me.

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you are asking...you want to create a `EmailTemplate` for the manager, too? And you have his address in the employee record? So what is the problem? Or do you need to get that address from another table? So you should show us the schema of the relevant tables.

Comment: @RenéVogt I want to create a template for manager too but want it to be sent out as soon as form is submitted.. i.e. one to use and the other to manager and I have the email or both available in the employees table I can't figure out how to change the template id for each of them as I want them to see different information in the email body

Comment: Does `Employee` have a `Manager` property (or similar)?

Comment: @GertArnold Yes id does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<EmailTemplate> emailTemps = new List<EmailTemplate>();

    emailTemps.AddRange( db.Employees.Where(a => a.Username == username).Select(b => new EmailTemplate{
       EmailTo = b.employeeDetails.Email,
       Subject = b.somesubject,
       EmailFrom = "from@mydomain.com",
       EmailDelivered = "No",
       EmailPriority = "Normal",
       EmailReference = b.formId
       EmailTemplateId = 1
    }).ToArray());

    emailTemps.AddRange(emailTemps.Select(e=> new EmailTemplate{
           EmailTo = ManagerEmailTo,
           Subject = e.Subject,
           EmailFrom = e.EmailFrom,
           EmailDelivered = e.EmailDelivered,
           EmailPriority = e.EmailPriority,
           EmailReference = e.EmailReference 
           EmailTemplateId = 2
        });
```

Now `emailTemps` contains both lists.

Comment: Sorry if I was a little unclear but will this enable me to send out  two template one for user and the other for manager?

Comment: you want  each email to be sent for 2 people or set a condition that send to either a manager or a user?

Comment: I want each email to be sent to 2 users but with different `EmailTemplateId` because the manager will have some extra information regarding the employee

Comment: Thanks.. but shouldn't `EmailTo = e.EmailTo` the email address of manager?

Comment: @Code well change it as you wish

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
var emails = new List<EmailTemplate>();
var employeeDetails = db.Employees.Where(a => a.Username == username).Select(b => b).FirstOrDefault();
var menagerDetails = employeeDetails.Manager;

emails.Add(new EmailTemplate
{
    EmailTo = employeeDetails.Email,
    Subject = somesubject,
    EmailFrom = "from@mydomain.com",
    EmailDelivered = "No",
    EmailPriority = "Normal",
    EmailReference = formId
    EmailTemplateId = 1
});

emails.Add(new EmailTemplate
{
    EmailTo = menagerDetails.Email,
    Subject = somesubject,
    EmailFrom = "from@mydomain.com",
    EmailDelivered = "No",
    EmailPriority = "Normal",
    EmailReference = formId
    EmailTemplateId = 2
});
```

Emails contains both templates with different data - for employee and its manager.